# Proving a property of the largest limit point

Tags: analysis, limits, proof-verification, sequences-and-series

> > Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence. By Bolzano-Weierstraß this sequence does have a limit point. Let $\bar{a}$ denote the largest limit point of the sequence. Show that among all limit points of the sequence $\bar{a}$ is characterized by the following property:
> >     $$
> > \forall~\varepsilon >0~\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: a_n < \bar{a}+\varepsilon~\forall n\geqslant N
> > $$

I think I have to prove two things:

1. The property is not fullfilled for all limit points $\hat{a}<\bar{a}$ and
2. The property is fullfilled for $\bar{a}$.

Here is how I did it:

**1.** Let $\hat{a}<\bar{a}$ be a limit point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Consider
$$
\varepsilon':=\frac{1}{2}(\bar{a}-(\hat{a}+\varepsilon)).
$$
 Because $\bar{a}$ is a limit point there is a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
a_n>\bar{a}-\varepsilon'>\hat{a}+\varepsilon~\forall~n\geqslant n_0.
$$

**2.** Let $\varepsilon >0$. Suppose there is no $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n<\bar{a}+\varepsilon~\forall~n\geqslant N$. Then almost all $a_n\geqslant \bar{a}+\varepsilon$. Because there is no larger limit point than $\bar{a}$ this means that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does indeed have no limit points, because for all the points that seemed to be limit points there is a neighbourhood with only finite many $a_n$, which means that they are indeed no limit points.

This is a contradiction to Bolzano-Weierstraß.

---

Maybe you can tell me if my proof is okay and (if not) how the statement can be shown.

Thank you and greetings

Comment: **Comment:** If there were infinitely many terms of the sequence greater or equal to $\bar a +\epsilon$, the sequence would have a limit point in $[\epsilon,\infty)$, contrary to the fact that $\bar a$ is the largest such limit point.

Comment: Ah, okay. Bolzano-Weierstraß says there there must be a limit point. It cannot be in $(-\infty, \bar{a}+\varepsilon)$, because if infinitely many $a_n\geqslant \bar{a}+\varepsilon$ then there are only finite many in $(-\infty,\bar{a}+\varepsilon)$, so that each neighbourhood would contain only finite many points. So the existing limit point MUST BE in $[\bar{a}+\varepsilon,\infty)$. Which is a contradiction to the assumption that $\bar{a}$ is the largest limit point. - - Got it?

Comment: There can easily be infinitely many terms on both sides of $\bar a$. For example, take $a_n =(-1)^n/n$; then $a_n\rightarrow 0$ so $\bar a=0$, yet $a_{2n}\downarrow \bar a$ and $a_{2n+1}\uparrow \bar a$.

Comment: So my argumentation in my last comment was wrong? Sorry I am Bit confused now.

Comment: Consider the subsequence $\{b_i\}$ of terms that are greater than or equal to $\bar a +\epsilon$. This is a bounded sequence in $[\bar a +\epsilon, M]$ where $M$ is any upper bound on the original sequence. If this subsequence is infinite, it has a limit point in this same closed interval because the limit point lies in the closure of the sequence, which in turn lies in the closure of the interval, which is already closed. I.e., if the subsequence is infinite, it has a limit point strictly greater than $\bar a$. But any limit point of the subsequence is a limit point of the original sequence.

Comment: (continuation) So you conclude that there can only be finitely many terms of the original sequence greater than or equal to $\bar a + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, so there can be no limit point with this property either.